# Stencil - How are new fonts added?

Tags: bigcommerce

How or where is this variable defined in stencil?

```
{{ getFontsCollection }}
```

I'm hoping to include other google fonts in the theme. Are they automatically included if they are listed in schema.json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are added via the [config file](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/configjson-reference)

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Stencil Docs](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/reference-docs/handlebars-helpers-reference#handlebars-helpers-reference_injection), `getFontsCollection` is a handlebars injection helper function used to help you load the resource on the page:

`{{getFontsCollection}}`

The getFontsCollection helper is custom to Stencil. It returns a link tag that loads all selected font collections. It takes no parameters.

The [helper method](https://github.com/bigcommerce/paper-handlebars/blob/master/helpers/getFontsCollection.js) pulls from your global `getThemeSettings()` which are located in your config.json file.  Look for the `primary-font` and `secondary-font` fields

```
"settings": {
        "primary-font": "Google_Lato_700,400,300",
        "secondary-font": "Google_Droid+Serif_400italic,400,700",
        ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you are answering a question from 2016 that has already been answered...